# How to write the below eloquent query code using raw query in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My eloquent query:

```html
$data = (new Model())->whereDate('start_date', '<=', Carbon::today())
                ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', Carbon::today())
                ->count();
```

The raw query I have tried:

```html
$data = (new Model())->select(DB::raw("COUNT(id) as countData where date(start_date) <= NOW() and date(end_date) >= NOW()"))->get();
```

How can I write my eloquent query as raw query. The below raw query gives me syntax violation error;

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how you are constructing your query. If you inspect the generated SQL statement you'll see that the SQL `FROM` clause is actually on the end of your statement and not at all where it should be.

You'll want to split your `WHERE` clauses out and use either `where` or `whereRaw`. For example:

```
$data = (new Model)->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as countData'))
                ->whereRaw('date("start_date") <= NOW() AND date("end_date") >= NOW()')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little unclear but if you want to do what you did with eloquent in raw query, be noted that the **select** function of DB in raw by itself, so simply write your query inside **select** function:

```
$tableName = (new Model)->getTable();
$data = DB::select("
    SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `countData` FROM `$tableName`
    WHERE DATE(`start_date`) <= NOW() AND DATE(`end_date`) >= NOW()
")->first();
```

Alternatively you may use **whereRaw** function of your Model:

```
$data = Model::whereRaw(
    "DATE(`start_date`) <= NOW() AND DATE(end_date) >= NOW()"
)->count();
```